# Linq Left Join with Where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-5

I have this query that I am performing using entity framework 5 with MySql.

```
var employeeDetails = (from em in entities.employeemasters.AsEnumerable()
                       join sf in entities.salaryfitments.AsEnumerable()
                       on em.empID equals sf.empID into emsf
                       from x in emsf
                       where (x.edCode.ToString().Trim().Equals(txtEDCode.Text)
                       && x.edCode != "SYS001")
                       select new { em, x });
```

The `where (x.edCode.ToString().Trim().Equals(txtEDCode.Text)` checks to see if there are any earnings/deductions stored for that employee and if so I can be able to get the amount figure.

I would like the query to return all employees and if they do not have a particular earnings/deductions matching txtEDCode.Text, then return a default value.

I cannot place `.DefaultIfEmpty()` after  `where (x.edCode.ToString().Trim().Equals(txtEDCode.Text)`

What should I do to get the appropriate results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the whole entities I'd create a new object with only the fields I was interested in and use a [ternary if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to provide the default value in the select statement, for example.

```
select new { 
    name = x.Name, 
    salary = x.Salary, 
    code = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? "Blah" : x 
}
```

Comment: I have already modified my query a bit while waiting for an answer and implemented what you have written. Thanks, will mark your answer as correct.